# SharePoint Workflow Activity doesn't appear in SP Designer. Deployment was successful

Tags: c#, sharepoint, workflow, sharepoint-designer

I developed a SP Workflow Activity for SP Designer. The deployment is successful. In the webconfig-file the authorizedType is correctly inserted:

```
<authorizedType Assembly="WorkflowActivity, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5c8e215f3e395427" Namespace="AdventureWorksWFs" TypeName="*" Authorized="True" />
```

Source code:

```
public static DependencyProperty TestProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Test", typeof(string), typeof(TestSite));

    [Description("Name of the new Site")]
    [Category("Sites")]
    [Browsable(true)]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
    public string Test
    {
        get
        {
            return ((string)(base.GetValue(TestSite.TestProperty)));
        }
        set
        {
            base.SetValue(TestSite.TestProperty, value);
        }
    }

    protected override ActivityExecutionStatus Execute(ActivityExecutionContext executionContext)
    {
        using (SPSite siteCollection = new SPSite(Url))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = siteCollection.OpenWeb())
            {
                using (SPWeb testWeb = web.Webs.Add(Test)) 
                {
                    testWeb.Description = "This is a test!";
                    testWeb.Title = Test;
                }
            }
        }
        return ActivityExecutionStatus.Closed;
    }
```

This is the .actions file:

```
<WorkflowInfo>
  <Actions Sequential="then" Parallel="and">
    <Action Name="Create New Site" ClassName="TestActivity.TestSite"
        Assembly="TestActivity, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
        PublicKeyToken=5c25d241f3e851927" AppliesTo="all"
        Category="Sites">
      <RuleDesigner Sentence="Create TestSite">
        <FieldBind Field="Test" Text="test" DesignerType="TextBox" Id="1" />
      </RuleDesigner>
      <Parameters>
        <Parameter Name="Test" Type="System.String, mscorlib" Direction="In" />
      </Parameters>
    </Action>
  </Actions>
</WorkflowInfo>
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Show code. If you don't, how do you expect someone will point you to the right direction?

Comment: Show code. Explain more steps. You said "I develop a workflow activity" yet in the title you say the "workflow doesn't appear" - how can a workflow appear when you develop an activity?

Comment: sorry, I forgot to write that it is a Workflow ACTIVITY.

Answer (score 0):

Search the following reference:

•   Open the configuration file of the WebApplication where you installed the package: C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories[Port Web App]\web.config

•   Review to appear in the appropriate place the following two configuration entries that should create the installation of the solution:

```
 <SafeControl Assembly="TestActivity.TestSite, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5c25d241f3e851927" Namespace="TestActivity.TestSite" TypeName="*" Safe="True" SafeAgainstScript="False" />

  <authorizedType Assembly="TestActivity.TestSite, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5c25d241f3e851927" Namespace="TestActivity.TestSite" TypeName="*" Authorized="True" />
```

If you are not manually add them where appropriate.

Then verify that the file is TestActivity.TestSite.Actions into the appropriate directory:

C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\1033\Workflow\

Comment: Hi fbeperet, I checked all your advices and they're all alright.